# Ambiguity in relative magnitude of dimensions of a RotatedRect in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am trying to put thresholds on the aspect ratios of rotated rectangles obtained around certain objects in the image using OpenCV. To compare the aspect ratio of a rotated rectangle with the threshold, I need to take the ratio of the longer dimension and the shorter dimension of the rotated rectangle.

I am confused in this regard: what is the convention in OpenCV? Is rotatedRectanlge.size.width always smaller than rotatedRectangle.size.height? i.e., is the width of a rotated rectangle always assigned to the smaller of the two dimensions of the rotated Rectangle in OpenCV?

I tried running some code to find an answer. And, it seems like rotatedRectangle.size.width is actually the smaller dimension of a rotatedRectangle. But I still want some confirmation from anyone who has encountered something similar.

EDIT:  I am using fitEllipse to get the rotated rectangle and my version of OpenCV is 2.4.1.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no convention for a rotated rectangle per se, as [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rotatedrect) says

> The class represents rotated (i.e. not up-right) rectangles on a plane. Each rectangle is specified by the center point (mass center), length of each side (represented by cv::Size2f structure) and the rotation angle in degrees.

However, you don't specify what function or operation is creating your rotated rects - for example, if you used `fitEllipse` it may be that there is some internal detail of the algorithm that prefers to use the larger (or smaller) dimension as the width (or height).

Perhaps you could comment or edit your question with more information. As it stands, if you want the ratio of the longer:shorter dimensions, you will need to specifically test which is longer first.

**EDIT**

After looking at the OpenCV source code, the `fitEllipse` function contains the following code

```cpp
if( box.size.width > box.size.height )
{
    float tmp;
    CV_SWAP( box.size.width, box.size.height, tmp );
    box.angle = (float)(90 + rp[4]*180/CV_PI);
}
```

So, at least for this implementation, it seems that width is always taken as the shorter dimension. However, I wouldn't rely on that staying true in a future implementation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am using fitEllipse to get the rotated rectangle. Do you know if there is any convention that fitELlipse assigns the larger dimension as height?

Of course, I could put in a test to find the larger dimension before taking the aspect ratio. But it helps to know if there is any such convention for fitEllipse. Please do let me know if you have any idea about this!

Comment: Thanks! You are right. Your edited answer fits into my observation with some data. So, fitEllipse takes the shorter dimension as width. Thanks Roger. This was very helpful!